# React MultiSelect not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, multi-select, use-state

The problem is that when the value of the `MultiSelect` is not empty, the function that is being called on the `filterOptions` props of the `MultiSelect` keeps executing the `Http` call inside it.

```
import MultiSelect from "react-multi-select-component";
...


const [invoices,set_invoices] = useState([]);
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

function test(options, filter) {
    if (!filter) {
        return options;
    }
    var data={'invoice_number':'22'}
    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/get_invoice_by_number',data).then(
        response => {
            /* Matching the array elements to be like {lable:'',value:''} */
            var temp_invoices=[];
            for(var i =0;i<response.data.length;i++){
                temp_invoices.push({
                    label:response.data[i].invoice_number,
                    value:response.data[i].invoice_number
                })
            }
            /* This is updating the list with response.data that is coming from the API */
            set_invoices(temp_invoices);
            console.log('FIRED')

        },error =>{
            console.log(error);
        }
    )
    return options;

}


<MultiSelect
    options={invoices}
    value={selected}
    labelledBy={"Select"}
    onChange={setSelected}
    filterOptions={test}
/>
```

**The console.log shows this when i just type one letter in the input**

[image: This what happen when i type inside the MultiSelect input]

I tried to remove `set_invoices(temp_invoices);` from the `test function` and tried to type it only showed `FIRED` two times and only when typing.

I have been stuck on this since hours and not figuring out the problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting state `set_invoices(temp_invoices);` in your `test` function which will cause the re-render and the `test` function is executed again(and again...) resulting in infinite loop.

Also, `react-multi-select-component` library doesn't support async filtering. It will be too much of work/hack to make it work(dig source code, tweak it etc).

Instead, you may consider to use [react-select AsyncSelect](https://react-select.com/home#async)

Comment: Thank you, but i prefer `Ant Select`, since it is more dynamic and has a very clear documentations

Answer (score 0):

I used `Ant Select` instead of `MultiSelect` which has a very clear documentation and easy to work with it. I strongly recommend it.